# function php in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get to run a php loop once i press on a radio button. I realize that i have to do this using ajax. I am very new to ajax so im having a hard time getting this done. What happens now is that i cannot even press the radio button anymore and nothing shows up.

what i tried so far:

my loop(which works fine):
magazines.php:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'magazine', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
}
?>
```

Ajax in main page:

```
$('radio').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'magazines.php',
    success: function(){
         alert('success');
    }
});

return false;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: comment "return false;" and try

Comment: Nope, did not work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`radio` is a type selector, it matches `<radio>` elements which you don't have (and which don't exist in HTML).

You need to write a [selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) that actually matches your elements. e.g. `input`.

Comment: i gave the radio input a class and tried it that way which didnt work either.

Comment: ok... that is really weird. So that means there is something wrong with my url then?

Comment: if i remove the url i'll get the success message, but i dont get what is wrong with the url.

Comment: @kerv — Possibly. Or possibly the element doesn't exist when you try to bind the event handlers. You'd need to do more debugging. Look at the developer tools in your browser. Use the Network tab to see if the request is being made. If it is, then look at the response to give out what is wrong with it. If it isn't, then add console.log statements to see if the JS is being run at all and if `$('.foo').length` is non-zero.

Comment: @kerv — If you've narrowed it down to a problem with the request, then look at the developer tools. Check the console for cross origin errors. Check the network tab to see what request you are actually making and what the response is.

Comment: Alright i changed the url to url:index.php/magazines and i seem to be getting the message succes now. But it is not showing the stuff that the loop is supposed to show that is inside the magazines.php. I appreciate your help alot. Thanks.

Comment: @kerv — Your JavaScript is written to display an alert and not do anything with the response. If you want to show the response then you need to take the data and put it in your document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body').on('click','input:radio',function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'magazines.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('#your-selector').html(data);
      }
      });
})
```

Comment: I dont want to have an alert displayed. I want to have my loop run.

Answer (score 0):

**try this: its tested**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function(){
         $('input:radio').click(function() {
             console.log("clicked");
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'magazines.php',
                 success: function(response){
                     console.log(response);
                     alert('success');
                  }
             });
         return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, i am getting the message succes with this but it is not showing the loop for some reason. Ty for your help though.

Comment: who down voted me? I don't need it. I am trying to earn 50 reputation to add comment in another post.

Comment: @kerv, I didn't check code in 'magazines.php' file. because you said : "my loop works fine in magazines.php".

Comment: @ kerv, i am just printing some string stuff in "magazines.php" and its coming in response. so why down vote. :(

Answer (score -1):

please try this

```
$('radio').click(function() {
   $.get('magazines.php', {}, function(){
       alert('success');
   });
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.